# Can you get a standalone Windows key?

Tags: usb, keyboard

Old IBM mechanical keyboards are really nice to type on, but they lack a Windows key.

Can you buy one standalone? I imagine it having a USB cable and a single button.

Answer (score 14):

Consider using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to remap one of your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys to simulate the <kbd>Win</kbd> key. Alternatively, you you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> for the same functionality.

You can also get a custom [single switch keyboard](http://xkeys.com/xkeys.php) and program that to be the Windows key.

[image: single switch keys]

Comment: Ha. Beat me by a few seconds. I will delete my answer. :P

Comment: If the user wants windows key shortcuts, this does not solve the problem fully. Windows key and l to lock or with r to bring up run will not work. Thou if the OP is only after bringing up the start menu this will work just like it has for the last 17 years.

Comment: I like the big "red" panic button the best.  Kudos to your for enjoying the old "buckling spring" keyboards!

Comment: Autohotkey has a "WinKEY" Setting....

Comment: @Paperlantern AutoHotkey can effectively remap a key completely, and any keyboard shortcuts with the simulated key will work.

Answer (score 3):

There are buckling spring keyboards, with a full 101 or 104 keyset. After looking at trying to get a good newer "Model M" I ended up here http://www.pckeyboard.com/ trying to select a perfect choice for me, that came in a buckling spring model. I am using the "spacesaver" now.

You could say some of the feel of the old style is making a return, so checking out other options like Duckey , Daskeyboard, Cherry, enduropro, and many others before picking one would be a good idea.  Even sites discussing them is "big" [Geekboards](http://geekhack.org/showwiki.php?title=START%20HERE%20--%20The%20Geekhack%20Mechanical%20Keyboard%20Guide%20-%20Includes%20Glossary%20and%20Links)

A simple search at google for "mechanical keyboard" and restricting the search to "past year" will get lots of info.

So you can have your cake , with frosting, it will just take a fair ammount of research, to get the perfect one for you.

Answer (score 2):

Select a key that you absolutely will not miss. Lets take the 'Scroll Lock' key ('Rollen' in Germany).

I have never used that and probably never will.

In Windows it is possible to remap all keys with the registry, so the goal is to remap 'Scroll Lock' to 'Windows (left)'.

You can do that with the program [sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/). The easiest way to configure the program is to use a standard keyboard (with Windows key), so you can press the keys instead of searching them in the list.

Instructions:

Once you download and start sharpkeys click on 'Add'.

[image]

On the new window you have to select 'Type key' (1) and press the 'Lock Screen' key. Then select 'Type key' (2) and press 'Windows (left)'.

Or you can select them from the list:

- Special: Scroll Lock (00_46)
- Special: Left Windows (E0_5B)

Accept with 'Ok' and press 'Write to Registry'. Then restart your OS.

Now you can insert every Windows key combination by pressing 'Scroll Lock' + , 'Scroll Lock' + 'e' opens the Explorer for example.